# How to avoid joins using subqueries inside Specification?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I need to fetch some entites based on data that can only be found after 5 associations. I would like to avoid joining all the tables on the way and use the IN clause.

Here is a simple implementantion I found using only a couple of entities:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    private Long idFoo;
    private String name; 
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
    @Id
    private Long idBar;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idFoo")
    private Foo foo; 
}
```

Let's suppose I need to list all Foo objects according to a Bar property, let's say the idBar:

```
class FilterFooByIdBar extends Specification<Foo> {
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Foo> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        var subquery = query.subquery(Foo.class);
        var barRoot = subquery.from(Bar.class);

        subquery.select(barRoot.get("foo"))
                .where(builder.equal(barRoot.get("idBar"), 1L));

        return root.in(subquery);
    }
}
```

This works but the resulting SQL is something like that:

```
select foo0_.idFoo, foo0_.name 
from Foo foo0_ 
where foo0_.idFoo in (
    select bar1_.idFoo 
    from Bar bar1_ cross join Foo foo2_ 
    where bar1_.idFoo=foo2_.idFoo 
    and bar1_.idBar=1
);
```

I think that the join inside the subquery is useless and goes against my goal, I would like to do something like:

```
select foo0_.idFoo, foo0_.name 
from Foo foo0_ 
where foo0_.idFoo in (
    select bar1_.idFoo 
    from bar bar1_  
    where bar1_.idBar=1
);
```

Is there anyway to change the Specification and achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an exists subquery instead which is usually faster anyway and will also allow to eliminate the join if you are using the latest hibernate version.

```
class FilterFooByIdBar extends Specification<Foo> {
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Foo> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        var subquery = query.subquery(Foo.class);
        var barRoot = subquery.from(Bar.class);

        subquery.select(cb.literal(1))
                .where(cb.and(
                   cb.equal(barRoot.get("idBar"), 1L),
                   cb.equal(barRoot.get("foo"), root)
                );

        return cb.exists(subquery);
    }
}
```